# How to load balance > C100K?

Tags: scalability, load-balancing

Suppose that a hypotetical webapp keeps one connections per user (eg: chat app using comet, long pooling, etc...).
How can i load balance such thing to scale beyond the connection limit of a single machine (C10[0]K) ?

I can see round robin DNS as a solution, would like to know what else would be possible...

Comment: Are there not a million dupes of this question?

Comment: I also thought so, but couldn't find... could you point some?

Comment: Look to the right.

Answer (score 1):

dns load balancing will do but you don't have much control over it - better use a load balancer.

Comment: The problem is what to do when you exceed the capacity of a single load balancer.

Comment: have two or more load balancers handling the traffic, these can as well be mixed with dns round robin

Answer (score 1):

The far extreme of this is Geographic DNS distributing discrete round-robin IP address pools which in turn point to clustered hardware load-balancers using Virtual IP to handle failover.  I say hardware since the big hardware load-balancers are designed for truly massive connection-counts.

Comment: That's what i think too... do you have an idea of how much "massive" this count is?